# background printing issue with twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, printing

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and try to print page with background.
I tried all the options in the web browser , but it doesn't work.
If I don't include twitter bootstrap, the printing of the background works perfectly.
(by the way, on this particular page I'm not using anything related to TBS).

Is there anything I can do to make it work (a kind of reset ) without excluding TBS ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Bootstrap css file has an "@media print" section which sets the following css rule:

```
* {
    color: #000 !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
```

As you can see that sets all backgrounds to be transparent.

You'd need to override that in your custom style sheet or change it in the bootstrap.css file.